# Hi my task is to Create a Procedure to Print a client’s timetable for a week

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

Hi my task is to print Print a client’s timetable for a week. I made this procedure to print customer timetable. i couldnt figure out the errors ive made and can someone please help me to Print a client’s timetable for a week.

```
*Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
CUSTOMER_T_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
C_DATE        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) 
TIMETABLE_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
CUSTOMER_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   

Desc Timetable
Name              Null     Type         
----------------- -------- ------------ 
TIMETABLE_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
CLASS_DAY         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
CLASS_LOCATION    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
CLASS_START_TIME  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) 
CLASS_FINISH_TIME NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) 
WORKOUT_CLASS_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
TRAINER_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   

Desc Customers
Name             Null     Type          
---------------- -------- ------------- 
CUSTOMER_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)    
FIRST_NAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
LAST_NAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
AGE              NOT NULL NUMBER(38)    
ADDRESS          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100) 
CITY             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
MOBILE_PHONE     NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
EMAIL                     VARCHAR2(50)  
PICTURE                   BFILE()       
CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(5)     
*/


    Create or Replace Procedure PrintTimeTable_Procedure
    (T_Customer_id number Default null)
    As
    Begin
     FOR aRow IN (Select Cu.Customer_id,Cu.First_Name,CT.CUSTOMER_T_ID,
    CT.C_DATE,
    CT.TIMETABLE_ID,
    CT.CUSTOMER_ID,
    T.TIMETABLE_ID,   
    T.CLASS_DAY, 
    T.CLASS_LOCATION,
    T.CLASS_START_TIME, 
    T.CLASS_FINISH_TIME,
    From Customers Cu, customer_timetable CT, TimeTable T
    Where C.Customer_id = CT.CUSTOMER_ID 
    And CT.TIMETABLE_ID = T.TIMETABLE_ID
    and CT.Customer_id = T_Customer_id

     LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer ID: ' || aRow.Cu.EMPLOYEE_ID);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || aRow.Cu.FIRST_NAME);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || aRow.CT.C_DATE);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DAY: ' || aRow.T.Class_Day);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLASS LOCATION: ' || aRow.T.CLASS_LOCATION);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START TIME: ' || aRow.T.CLASS_START_TIME);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FINISH TIME: ' || aRow.T.CLASS_FINISH_TIME);
     END LOOP;


    PROMPT PrintTimeTable_Procedure Procedure

    Execute PrintTimeTable_Procedure;




/*C:\Users\venkatesh\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\VENKYPROsql
Error(12,14): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(20,22): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
Error(27,66): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     loop 
Error(34,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the end of the procedure statement

END PrintTimeTable_Procedure:

and you cannot use PROMPT inside a pl/sql procedure. It needs to be more like

```
Create or replace your procedure....  as
Begin
....
End;
/
BEGIN
PrintTimeTable_Procedure;
END;
```

It's not entirely clear if you are running this from SQLPlus or from and IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the END of the procedure and you're not using the right names for the record fields. You don't need to include the table alias in the field name (i.e. aRow.Cu.FIRST_NAME is wrong, the field is named FIRST_NAME, aRow.FIRST_NAME). Also, I can't see any field named EMPLOYEE_ID

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PrintTimeTable_Procedure (T_Customer_id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL) AS
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT Cu.Customer_id,
                      Cu.First_Name,
                      CT.CUSTOMER_T_ID,
                      CT.C_DATE,
                      CT.TIMETABLE_ID,
                      CT.CUSTOMER_ID,
                      T.TIMETABLE_ID,   
                      T.CLASS_DAY, 
                      T.CLASS_LOCATION,
                      T.CLASS_START_TIME, 
                      T.CLASS_FINISH_TIME,
               FROM Customers Cu, customer_timetable CT, TimeTable T
               WHERE C.Customer_id = CT.CUSTOMER_ID 
               AND CT.TIMETABLE_ID = T.TIMETABLE_ID
               AND CT.Customer_id = T_Customer_id) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer ID: ' || aRow.CUSTOMER_ID);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || aRow.FIRST_NAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE: ' || aRow.C_DATE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DAY: ' || aRow.Class_Day);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLASS LOCATION: ' || aRow.CLASS_LOCATION);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START TIME: ' || aRow.CLASS_START_TIME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FINISH TIME: ' || aRow.CLASS_FINISH_TIME);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

PROMPT PrintTimeTable_Procedure Procedure
BEGIN
  PrintTimeTable_Procedure;
END;
/
```